# What rights do students in the U.S. have re gender pronouns?

Tags: united-states, legal-issues, gender

What federally protected legal rights does a transgender student in the U.S. have re gender pronouns used in referring to the student?

This question was inspired by the [recent discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/gendered-pronoun-usage) of gender pronouns at Academia Meta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the legalese of a specific geographic region and not about academia.

Comment: @CapeCode: It’s about a legal question in the academic setting, very relevant to many academics.  Similarly, it’s not universal in geographical scope, but its scope is large enough to include a very significant fraction of users here.  Browsing the [legal-issues] tag shows plenty of similar questions that were well-received and produced useful answers.

Comment: @CapeCode then we can close all the questions in the legal issues tag, because by definition they only apply to a specific geographic region (unless there are academic war crimes :) ).

Comment: @scaaahu I find it very clear. Legal rights as given by whichever jurisdiction falls into that. From the answer, it seems federal law applies here, but if it were regulated by state law, a good answer would say "this depends on the state, this is how it is in Indiana, check your state".

Comment: @Davidmh The OP did not even say it's the legal right  that is being asked here. Re: _What rights does a transgender student in the U.S. ..._ Legal rights is my guess.

Comment: @Davidmh Agreed. I'm strongly in favor of closing all legal-related questions.

Comment: @CapeCode [I have posted a meta question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3497/should-legal-questions-be-closed-as-too-narrow/3498#3498)

Comment: I can't see that this is any more off-topic than any other legal question pertaining to academia (of which, as noted on meta, there are many here), and can't help thinking that its closing has more to do with the content :-/

Comment: If this were an ethics or normative question, of the variety "how should students be treated..." I'd upvote and argue it is absolutely on topic here and not relative to opinion. But I'm also in the camp of those who aren't comfortable with legal interpretations of specific federal laws being the primary gist of the question, especially on issues which are actively changing with every new appeal and supreme court decision - such that even legal experts have trouble with active areas like this, and proper interpretation of individual vs institutional liability.

Comment: @BrianDHall - I edited the sentence that gets at the legal ramifications.  Essentially, the power of OCR lies in the threat to cut off public funding.  Not by a percentage -- it is all or nothing.  Publicly funded educational institutions are therefore quite careful to carry out remediation measures required by OCR. ... OCR moves slowly but it is relentless and consistent in its interpretations of Title IX and 504.  Take a look at the LGBT-related case resolutions posted at http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/lgbt.html.

Comment: Here's how it works: Congress passes a law, instructs the appropriate body to flesh out the law with regulations (for a great account of the role the disabled movement played in the creation of the 504 regulations, see ["A Short History of the 504 Sit-in"](http://dredf.org/504-sit-in-20th-anniversary/short-history-of-the-504-sit-in/)), and funds and mandates an agency to *enforce* that law and that set of regulations.  In the case of Title IX, and Section 504 of the Rehabilitation Act (which prohibits discrimination in public education on the basis of disability), that enforcing body is OCR.

Comment: The "Dear Colleague letter" guidance cited in my answer states clearly that this recently published document does not *change* how OCR has been enforcing Title IX, it, along with the accompanying "Examples" document, simply spells out the expectations more clearly and explicitly.

Comment: @SimonW The policy on legal question, if any, isn't consistently applied: [Has the stance on questions pertaining to legal issues changed?](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/2141/452)

Answer (score 17):

I think [another answer here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/77828/11365) is [misleading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77827/what-rights-do-students-in-the-u-s-have-re-gender-pronouns#comment190727_77828), so I am writing to clarify what federally protected rights transgender students in the U.S. can reasonably expect at this time.

As things currently stand:

- The federal government is not allowed to pursue Title IX investigations that interpret Title IX's sex discrimination prohibition to include discrimination based on gender identity.
- The Department of Justice and Department of Education have rescinded guidance (issued by the previous administration) that instructed schools to treat discrimination based on gender identity as a Title IX issue.
- The U.S. Supreme Court may indicate later this year whether Title IX protections apply to transgender students who face discrimination based on gender identity.

---

Previous federal guidance in the [Dear Colleague letter of May 2016](http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/letters/colleague-201605-title-ix-transgender.pdf) considered discrimination based on gender identity to be sex-based discrimination. According to this interpretation, Title IX protections would then apply to transgender students who are subject to discrimination because of their gender identity.  This would certainly *not* have required school employees to use gender-neutral language as a general rule, but that letter did support e.g.

- a student's right to ask school employees and contractors to use pronouns consistent with their gender identity,
- the school's Title IX responsibility to mitigate (to the degree that they can) the harassment of students due to gender identity. There is legal precedent (see footnote 9 in the document linked above) to suggest that persistent misgendering can be considered sex-based harassment if it is severe or pervasive: "Persistent failure to use the employee’s correct name and pronoun may constitute unlawful, sex-based harassment if such conduct is either severe or pervasive enough to create a hostile work environment"

However, this interpretation - that Title IX protections apply to gender identity - was challenged in the courts in [Texas v United States](https://www.texasattorneygeneral.gov/files/epress/files/2016/complaint_FM.pdf). An [August 2016 injunction](https://www.texasattorneygeneral.gov/files/epress/Texas_et_al_v._U.S._et_al_-_Nationwide_PI_(08-21-16).pdf) bars the federal government from enforcing the interpretation of Title IX put forth in the Dear Colleague letter:

> Defendants are enjoined from enforcing the Guidelines against Plaintiffs and their respective schools, school boards, and other public, educationally-based institutions. Further, while this injunction remains in place, Defendants are enjoined from initiating, continuing, or concluding any investigation based on Defendants’ interpretation that the definition of sex includes gender identity in Title IX’s prohibition against discrimination on the basis of sex.

The U.S. Department of Justice indicated an intent to appeal that Texas decision, and [in November 2016](http://files.eqcf.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/13772486-Appellant-Motion-Partial-Stay-1.pdf), asked for a partial stay on the injunction, arguing that the injunction should only apply to the states involved in the lawsuit. A hearing on that motion for a partial stay would have taken place in February 2017. However, the new administration's Department of Justice [withdrew that motion](http://www.washingtonblade.com/content/files/2017/02/Trump-DOJ-trans.pdf) just before the scheduled hearing, noting that the "parties are currently considering how best to proceed in this appeal."  Shortly afterwards, the Department of Justice and Department of Education issued a [new Dear Colleague letter](http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/letters/colleague-201702-title-ix.docx) withdrawing the guidance in the May 2016 letter.

Meanwhile, in [March 2017](http://www.lgbtqnation.com/2017/02/supreme-court-will-hear-gavin-grimms-landmark-transgender-rights-case-march/) the U.S. Supreme Court will hear a related case, in which they may decide whether Title IX protections apply to gender identity. This case, too, is complicated by the withdrawal of the May 2016 letter, [a move that has been communicated to the court](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C5TulfPWAAEqtq1.jpg).

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort you took to write this in a balanced and accurate way; the result is a clear and helpful answer.

Comment: I had not seen the Texas injunction.  Had I known about it I would have waited to post my question, and my answer.  It was not my intention to introduce a legal polemic here at Academia SE. ... That said, having now looked at the Texas injunction you found; I have to say it appears to be about bathrooms, not pronouns.  Also note that the injunction is apparently not having the broad, sweeping effect intended.  In some recent cases, the Texas injunction was found to be of limited relevance.

Comment: @aparente001 This isn't the right place for discussing the US legal system; if you want to learn how to correctly interpret the injunction (or the other documents you've cited in your answer), or if you think I've misstated something and want to get a second opinion, take it to [law.se].

Comment: @ff524 - I made no assertion you misstated anything.  The injunction certainly makes things more messy, and more polemical than I thought this topic would be.  I agree fine legal points have no place on this site.  I thought this was a straightforward Q & A, as I was unaware of the Texas challenge. ... The injunction order is itself complex, but judging from some cases that have been ruled on since it was released, it has not prevented parents from continuing to advocate strongly and successfully for their transgender children's right to use the bathroom of choice.  Further responses will ...

Comment: have to wait until tomorrow....  Good night.

Comment: really nice answer :)

Comment: Could this be updated with the results of that March 2017 SCOTUS case? (Not looking for a complete update, just that last bit is kind of a cliffhanger.)

Answer (score 14):

As recently clarified by a ["Dear Colleague" letter](http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/letters/colleague-201605-title-ix-transgender.pdf) from the U.S. Department of Education's Office for Civil Rights, under Title IX, in educational institutions receiving public funding, transgender students have the right to be referred to by their chosen gender pronouns.  Also, educational institutions must "take reasonable steps to protect students’ privacy related to their transgender status, including their birth name or sex assigned at birth. [...] A school may maintain records with this information, but such records should be kept confidential."

For additional clarification, also see OCR's accompanying publication, "[Examples of Policies and Emerging Practices for Supporting Transgender Students](http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/oese/oshs/emergingpractices.pdf)".

In the referenced Meta discussion, one user asserted, "Gendered pronouns are not offensive content with respect to the Be Nice policy that all Stack Exchange users are required to follow."

That may be true -- after all, Stack Exchange sites are not subject to Title IX -- but as the above-cited guidance from OCR shows, using a non-preferred gendered pronoun in a public educational setting is not only offensive to a transgender individual, if it is done on a public campus, it could result in the institution **losing public funding** [bold text added 10/6/16 to be more precise].

---

**Edit 10/5/16**, response to comment

> Note that Title IX [...] does not require gender neutral pronouns as a general rule.

The Dear Colleague letter recognizes that "gender transition can happen swiftly or over a long duration of time."  Recognizing that a student may feel gender fluid during the process of transition, and recognizing students' right to privacy, the take-home message that I got from the OCR documents is that when in doubt, avoidance of gendered pronouns can be the most sensitive course of action.

While the OCR documents cited do not state this explicitly, they do support it.  The "Examples of Policies and Emerging Practices" include, as positive examples, the following quotes from state and district policies:

- "If you are unsure about a student’s preferred name or pronouns, it is appropriate to privately and tactfully ask the student what they prefer to be called." (DCPS)
- [Faculty and staff training should include] “gender-neutral language and practices.” (Massachusetts)
- “As with most other issues involved with creating a safe and supportive environment for transgender students, the best course is to engage the student, and possibly the parent, with respect to name and pronoun use, and agree on a plan to reflect the individual needs of each student to initiate that name and pronoun use within the school." (New York)
- [Schools are advised to] "collect or maintain information about students’ gender only when necessary." (Massachusetts)
- “When speaking with other staff members, parents, guardians, or third parties, school staff should not disclose a student’s preferred name, pronoun, or other confidential information pertaining to the student’s transgender or gender nonconforming status without the student’s permission." (Chicago)

It can be challenging to speak or write in English without gendered pronouns!  OCR demonstrates that with a little effort, it can be done without confusion, and without too much awkwardness: http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/investigations/more/02131220-a.pdf

Comment: I think your final claim ("if it is done on a public campus, it is also illegal") is still an open question. The Obama administration, which is charged with executing the law, has interpreted Title IX a certain way; but unless I'm mistaken, that interpretation has been challenged, and the challenge is still making its way through the Federal courts (which are charged with interpreting the law, and whose interpretation, once available, will supersede that of the executive branch).

Comment: I find your last two paragraphs to be somewhat out of place here. If you want to make a statement about site policy, please do so in the referenced meta discussion. (Also note that Title IX, like Stack Exchange, does not require gender neutral pronouns as a general rule. Gendered pronouns are not generally "illegal" in a public educational setting - the documents you cite only suggest that _intentional misgendering after being asked to use specific pronouns preferred by that individual_ are a potential Title IX violation.)

Comment: You may want to clarify that "a student has the right to be referred to by their chosen gender pronouns" really means "the school has the obligation to refer to a student by their preferred gender pronouns when asked to do so by the student". I mean, of course the student has the right to be referred to by their preferred pronouns, can you imagine if it were forbidden for the student to be referred to by their preferred pronouns?

Comment: @ff524 I find this whole Q&A to be out of place here. This isn't law.SE, this is academia.SE.

Comment: @Seth this is a legal issue pertaining academics in the US, I don't find it out of place.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think you're misunderstanding the word "right". The question is whether the school has an obligation to use preferred pronouns. If there's no obligation, it's just up to the individual teacher or school to set their own rules. I think no one is even suggesting that schools are forced by law to use the pronoun of the student's assigned gender against their will.

Comment: @nitro2k01 Of course no one is suggesting that, but I find that "I have the right to be treated with respect" doesn't mean the same thing as "You are legally obligated to treat me with respect". For starters, the subject is different in the two sentences. What is the point of staying vague?

Comment: @ruakh - Would you care to provide a link?  Would you care to provide an answer?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I fail to see the difference. "_I_ have the legal right to be treated with respect _by you_", "_You_ have the legal obligation to treat _me_ with respect".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - I think if you look at the OCR letter, things will become clearer for you.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: I edited this answer to correct the claim that Title IX violations are "illegal". They are not illegal (you cannot be charged with a crime for this), nor in general are they even a civil cause of action; rather, they could in toto expose the *institution* to legal liability or issues with funding agencies.

Comment: The reference to SE seems misguided. Honestly, I cannot help but feel that there is quite some confusion about which types of problems are trying to be solved with which type of regulations.

Comment: You seem to be more intent on making a statement about site policy than actually helping transgender readers understand their rights. (To the point of implying that transgender students should expect that everyone at their institutions will use gender neutral pronouns as a general rule, or that schools will lose federal funding if they do not use gender neutral pronouns as a general rule, which is just not accurate.) I have downvoted this answer because many parts of it are misleading and potentially detrimental to transgender students who are actually trying to understand their rights.

Comment: "If you are unsure about a student’s preferred name or pronouns, it is appropriate to privately and tactfully ask the student what they prefer to be called." -- this also applies to students whose gender you can not infer from their names.

Comment: @aparente001, I have no isea why you think the OCR letter uses gender neutral language, as it refers to the student only in pronouns appropriate for the gender identification of the student.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - You are right.  The link in my answer was not the right one.  I meant to post the following letter as an example of gender-neutral language: http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/investigations/more/02131220-a.pdf.  Apologies for the error in the post, which I have just corrected.